# How to assign the elements of a list as file names in python?

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, io, python-3.5

I am trying to assign the elements of a list as names for some files that live in a directory, so far I created a function that recover the name of a each file from a directory and returns them in a list:

```
def retrive(directory_path):
    path_names = []
    for filename in sorted(glob.glob(os.path.join(directory_path, '*.pdf'))):
        retrieved_files = filename.split('/')[-1]
        path_names.append(retrieved_files)
    print (path_names)
```

The above function returns in a list the names of each file, then I am writing the files into another directory as follows:

```
    path = os.path.join(new_dir_path, "list%d.txt" % i)
    #This is the path of each new file:
    #print(path)
    with codecs.open(path, "w", encoding='utf8') as filename:
        for item in [a_list]:
            filename.write(item+"\n")
```

Finally, my question is: how can I assign as a name of each file, each element of `path_names`?, something like this line:

```
path = os.path.join(new_dir_path, "list%d.txt" % i)
```

I also tried to use the `format()` function. However I still cant assign the the correct name to each file.

Here's the full script:

```
def transform_directoy(input_directory, output_directory):    
    import codecs, glob, os
    from tika import parser
    all_texts = []
    for filename in sorted(glob.glob(os.path.join(input_directory, '*.pdf'))):
        parsed = parser.from_file(filename)
        texts = parsed['content']
        all_texts.append(texts)

    for i , a_list in enumerate(all_texts):
        new_dir_path = output_directory


        #print(new_dir_path)
        path = os.path.join(new_dir_path, "list%d.txt" % i)
        with codecs.open(path, "w", encoding='utf8') as filename:
            for item in [a_list]:
                filename.write(item+"\n")
```

The desired output will consist of the actual names of each processed file.

Comment: Why are you opening the files when all you want is their names?

Comment: And why are you using `codecs.open()` instead of plain `open()`?

Comment: Thanks for the help guys, because I am rewriting them and processing them in different formats @JohnGordon

Comment: @TigerhawkT3 I am preprocessing them... I omitted some parts of the code just for space reasons.

Comment: Go ahead and post that code.  This code sample isn’t enough for us to help you.

Comment: I edited the question with more details, thanks guys.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You’re almost there:

```
for path_name in path_names:
    path = os.path.join(new_dir_path, "list%s.txt" % path_name)
    #This is the path of each new file:
    #print(path)
    with codecs.open(path, "w", encoding='utf8') as f:
        for item in [a_list]:
            f.write(item+"\n")
```

---

Update based on updated code sample.  You are using different loops here, and that is not ideal unless you are doing processing in between the two loops.  Since I am going to keep that structure, we are going to have to make sure to associate each block of content with the original filename.  The best structure for that is a dict, and in case order is important, we use an `OrderedDict`.  Now, when we’re looping over the filename, content pairs in the `OrderedDict` we’ll want to change the extension of the file to match the new file type.  Luckily, python has some nice utilities for file/path manipulation in the `os.path` module.  `os.path.basename` can be used to strip off the directory from a file and `os.path.splitext` will strip off an extension from a filename.  We use both of those to get just the filename without the extension and then append `.txt` to designate the new file type.  Putting it all together, we get :

```
def transform_directoy(input_directory, output_directory):    
    import codecs, glob, os
    from collections import OrderedDict
    from tika import parser
    all_texts = OrderedDict()
    for filename in sorted(glob.glob(os.path.join(input_directory, '*.pdf'))):
        parsed = parser.from_file(filename)
        filename = os.path.basename(filename)
        texts = parsed['content']
        all_texts[filename] = texts

    for i, (original_filename, a_list) in enumerate(all_texts.items()):
        new_filename, _ = os.path.splitext(original_filename)
        new_filename += '.txt'
        new_dir_path = output_directory

        #print(new_dir_path)
        path = os.path.join(new_dir_path, new_filename)
        # Print out the name of the file we are processing
        print('Transforming %s => %s' % (original_filename, path,))
        with codecs.open(path, "w", encoding='utf8') as filename:
            for item in [a_list]:
                filename.write(item+"\n")
```

---

Second update:  OP asked how I would write this code if this was all that there was, so here goes:

```
# move imports to top of file:  PEP 8
import codecs, glob, os
from tika import parser

def transform_directoy(input_directory, output_directory):    
    for filename in sorted(glob.glob(os.path.join(input_directory, '*.pdf'))):
        parsed = parser.from_file(filename)
        parsed_content = parsed['content']
        original_filename = os.path.basename(filename)
        new_filename, _ = os.path.splitext(original_filename)
        new_filename += '.txt'
        path = os.path.join(output_directory, new_filename)
        # Print out the name of the file we are processing
        print('Transforming %s => %s' % (original_filename, path,))
        # no need for a second loop since we can piggy back off the first loop
        with codecs.open(path, "w", encoding='utf8') as filename:
            # No need for a for loop here since our list only has one item
            filename.write(parsed_content)
            filename.write("\n")
```

Comment: Thanks for the help!. However I am not preserving the original name of files, also one file is missing when I rewrite them, any idea of how to proceed?. THANKS!

Comment: Your question was literally:  `Finally, my question is: how can I assign as a name of each file, each element of path_names?` which to me meant, I want to preserve the original file names.  So, please edit your question to state exactly what question you want answered and post your *entire* code.

Comment: Thanks for the help 2ps I updated the question with all the script, thanks!

Comment: @tumbleweed:  I have updated the sample code.  I took out the directory name and added in a more descriptive print statement.  Let me know if you need more help.

Comment: @tumbleweed: There you go.

Comment: Could you provide some explanation about how you escaped and assign the actual name of the file?

Comment: Thanks for the help 2ps... you mentioned that using two different loops is not a pythonic way to solve this problem, which is a nicer way to do this?.

Comment: Amazing, thank you very much this will help to improve my logic!